# Cross-compiling QT apps for a raspberry pi - Cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I want to be able to use the QT Creator on my full-sized desktop to be able to develop and compile qt apps and deploy them to the pi.

I followed this guide: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Create#QtonPi_App_SDK

I am trying to get the hello-qtonpi project to compile. Using the compiler and the toolchain for the pi, I get two errors during compiling:

```
/opt/qtonpi/lib/gcc/armv5tel-qtonpi-linux-gnueabi/4.5.4/../../../../armv5tel-qtonpi-linux-gnueabi/bin/as: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/qtonpi/libexec/gcc/armv5tel-qtonpi-linux-gnueabi/4.5.4/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked that these two libraries were installed on my pi, and the rsynced /lib and /usr/lib from the pi to my sys-root folder.

I tried using the QT Creators Add Library -> System Library tool, and selected e.g. libz.so, as it didn't show the so.1 one. It added the following line to the .pro file:

```
unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -lz
```

However it still didn't get rid of the error.

How should I include these libraries or tell the compiler where to look from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both error messages about libz and libmpc are not related to target libraries missing but to the **host part**.

Your cross-compilation toolchain have been built as a dynamic one, so you need to have on your host all libraries resolving dependencies.

Since libz.so.1 is quite common,maybe you are running a 64 bit host but your toolchain have been built for 32 bits. In this case, you need to find package providing 32 bits version of libz.so.1 and libmpc.so.2.

Comment: I installed the 32-bit versions of both libraries on the host + one other. Now it is complaining about missing version information for libz.so.1. On the console it says that it "could not find absolute location of file /lib/libz.so.1". Any ideas?

Comment: Well whatever the reason was, it was fixed by deleting and recreating the symlink form .so.1 to .so.1.2.3